# CSS style difference between static and dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

When I create a DOM element with Javascript like this

```
$(document.createElement('div')).attr('id', 'box').appendTo('.parent');
```

...the height of `td` elements (and some others) inside the div gets distorted. However, when I specify the div in the markup:

```
<div id="box"></div>
```

...the styles are the way they should be.

Why is dynamic DOM element creation distorting CSS styles and how should I fix it?

Edit 1: I've already tried inspecting the `div` and changing some styles, but it didn't help.

Edit 2: I've recreated it in jsfiddle and it works there without problems (strangely enough). Just so you know, here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3cyFD/ My problem is that when I click on "Click me", the datepicker appears, but there are abnormal spaces between rows (the `td` cells of the table).

Comment: A fiddle would be useful here

Comment: It seems you are creating invalid markup. Can you reproduce the problem on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I'm trying, but it's tricky. The contents of the div is a JQuery datepicker.

Comment: you may need to initialize the datepicker?

Comment: It's not really possible to recreate this in a fiddle, there's just too much going on and I'm not sure which parts of the script influence this bug.

Comment: Guys, I've recently noticed this too but in a separate scenario using a <form> and some inputs. Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/NCfym/

Comment: Actually, now that I wrote a jsfiddle to check it... it looks like the issue is fixed if the "static" markup is written on 1 line similar to the **append** function... http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/NCfym/1/ But that still doesn't explain why the CSS is different when the mark up is not written/appended on 1 line??

Comment: it's not related. @projeqht only got many whitespaces between tags... :-)

Comment: Now that I checked it... no it isn't. The above solution didn't work in my situation.

Comment: can u give us a link to an url to check if it is too complicate for a fiddle?

Comment: Sorry guys, I thought it would be related but yeah you're right about the white spaces, I'll do some research on that since I didn't realize that about the white spaces until just now :P

Comment: If it's too complicated for a fiddle, it's too complicated for a single question. Breaking it down will help isolate the problem so we can better solve it.

Comment: @BastianRang I only have it running on a local host.

Comment: so anybody can be really helpful... :(

Comment: I've recreated it in jsfiddle and it works there without problems. Just so you know, here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3cyFD/
My problem is that when I click on "Click me", the datepicker appears, but there are abnormal spaces between rows (the td cells of the table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My strong assumption is that you have a CSS styling element out there you are not thinking of. That's been my experience when I've been stuck like that.

Using Chrome or Firefox inspect the element you have. You've already said it is not the divs but it sounds like that wouldn't be the issue anyway. Start with your td, then move to tr, then to table. Margins and padding might be your biggest culprits, but look for any attributes, including min-heights, and things along those lines. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I've fixed the problem. The issue was caused by the width of the td element. The datepicker's width was set to 200px, which was too wide for a td cell with a width of 170px. I simply moved the datepicker to another (wider) div and it works now.